# How to drive a 1MHz Ultrasound-TD1000KA

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, driver

I want to measure the Sediment of water. So I chose a 1MHz Ultrasonic Transducer sensor with the ability to work underwater and also can recognize the sediment under water.

The output of the sensor is analog, but I need a driver to convert to digital.
I need your help to suggest to me what should I do. How can I prepare an electrical circuit? Does anyone know what's the best way?

This is the link of the specification of the sensor:
http://chinaultrasound.com/product/1mhz-ultrasonic-transducer-depth-measurement-td1000ka/

Thanks so much.

Comment: Your link doesn't work.  Also, what specifically do you need the digital output to do?

Comment: http://chinaultrasound.com/product/1mhz-ultrasonic-transducer-depth-measurement-td1000ka/  is your link.   The output you get from the transducer will be a waveform, at the frequency you send out, which varies in amplitude with the strength of the reflection from whatever is present, at the time that it takes for the beam to travel out and back again. You can turn that into a digital signal if all you're looking for is a time between getting no signal reflected, and getting a strong signal back from the target. You could use just a comparator, but that would mean that the level would be fixed

Answer (score 1):

To drive it as the datasheet specifies you need a precise 1MHZ 100 to 200 volt pulse generator with a 2% duty cycle, or a pulse width of 20ns. Too wide a pulse or too high a voltage may damage the sensor.

Reflected return time = distance to sediment density. Reflected signal strength indicates sediment density. If the sensor is in a controlled xy motion then both time and strength values will change, so you can form a map-if that is your long-term goal.

To process this data you would need LabVIEW and a fast digitizer board (10msps)to extract and display the results (you or a third party writes the code) so the final image and stats have useful meaning.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
Actually, I want to measure the level of water of a tube with about 30 cm in diameter. and also Sediment of water of the tube.
I bought 2 type of this model sensor, and want to understand the amount of water of the tube and also the sediment that stores end of the tube. Then check the results on an HMI. So, the output of sensors is analog. I should set an analog-to-digital converter between sensors and HMI. But I don't know how can I do that. maybe a driver with a digital output can be useful.
The COM port of my HMI is RS232/485. There are some electrical circuits that wo

Comment: if that 20 ns pulse requirement is true, then OP might have problem with too low frequency of arduino.  You need at least 50 Mhz clock to generate that short pulse with microprocessor

Comment: yes, you are right. Because these are just sensor and they need a converter to work.
Can I use this module for my project? 
https://www.jahankitshop.com/getattach.aspx?id=4635&Type=Product

Is it possible to replace the sensor with mine? I think the difference between them is frequency.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you having a look at this [open source](https://github.com/kelu124/echomods) repo (disclaimer: it's mine). You will find high voltage pulser design and control, as well as analog to get it back to a high speed adc to a raspberry. Working too on a ice40 design, will push if of interest.

Tldr: open source hardware matching your requirement exist